# how to wrap every divs using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I tried to wrap every .test1 and .test2 class into one div tag but its wrapping whole div class. Please suggest.

**HTML**

```
<div class="test1">This is demo paragraph1.</div>
<div class="test2">This is demo paragraph2.</div>
<div class="test1">This is demo paragraph1.</div>
<div class="test2">This is demo paragraph2.</div>
<div class="test1">This is demo paragraph1.</div>
<div class="test2">This is demo paragraph2.</div>
```

**Excepted:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="test1">This is demo paragraph1.</div>
    <div class="test2">This is demo paragraph2.</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="test1">This is demo paragraph1.</div>
    <div class="test2">This is demo paragraph2.</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="test1">This is demo paragraph1.</div>
    <div class="test2">This is demo paragraph2.</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(".test1, .test2").wrapAll("<div class="container"></div>");
```

Comment: Use `.wrap` instead, if I understand correctly your question... By the way, watch your quotes

Comment: Watch your quotes in your wrapAll function.

Comment: may I've similar divs. that time its not working

Comment: I have added my expectation

Comment: That's not something you'll be able to easily with a single line.

Comment: but i'm not able to wrap it, pls suggest

Comment: @freedomn-m- Agreed, not a single line, but it's not too bad...

Comment: @cale_b I see my reverse psychology comment made you rise to the challenge!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The quotation marks in your jQuery (`"<div class="container"></div>"`) are causing an error.
2. Be sure to run this in a [document ready function](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready)
3. The clarified expectation is a bit trickier, but possible assuming there are always groups of two, using the [addBack](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/) function.

[This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fpL7r4uu/2/) shows one way to make it work, based on the assumptions above:

```
// no-conflict safe shorthand document ready
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".test1").each(function() {
      $(this).next(".test2").addBack().wrapAll('<div class="container"></div>');
  });
});
```

Comment: Nice use of `.addBack()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can go this way, using CSS [adjacent sibling combinator (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) for quick selection:

```js
$('.test1 + .test2').each(function() {
    $(this).prev().addBack().wrapAll('<div class="container" />');
});
```

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">This is demo paragraph1.</div>
<div class="test2">This is demo paragraph2.</div>
<div class="test1">This is demo paragraph1.</div>
<div class="test2">This is demo paragraph2.</div>
<div class="test1">This is demo paragraph1.</div>
<div class="test2">This is demo paragraph2.</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5fh1pkw/).

Please note, for older versions of jQuery, instead of `addBack()` method, should use `andSelf()`.